# Increment AmpScript for loop by more than 1

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

Is there a way to increment an AmpScript for loop by more than 1, for example by 2? (Please excuse the logic within the for loop - it is just a quick example).

```
SET @RowCount = 21

IF @RowCount > 10 THEN
  FOR @i = 10 to @RowCount DO
    SET @Value = FIELD(ROW(@foo, @i)), "Value")
  NEXT @i
  /*NEXT SET @i = ADD(@i, 2), would this work?*/
ENDIF
```

Basically I am trying to make ampscript act like this for loop:

```
for(int i = 10; i <= RowCount; i +=  2){
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you can reassign `@i`, but you can use the AMPScript [mod()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#mod) function to take action on every other row:

```
%%[
SET @RowCount = 10

FOR @i = 1 to @RowCount DO

  if mod(@i,2) == 0 then
    outputline(concat("<br>i: ",@i))
  endif

NEXT @i
]%%
```

**Output**

```
i: 2 
i: 4 
i: 6 
i: 8 
i: 10
```